# ical parser android

Tags: java, android, calendar, icalendar

I'm trying to pull events from my google calendar into a list view (most likely). I'm able to access .ics file but when I open the file in a text editor I see tags like `UID CREATED LASTMODIFIED` and many others. The description of the events is not really visible and the info corresponding to tags like `DTSTART` is not readable. I'm wondering what I've to read/do further to make the information on it so that I can make sense of it? Also is there a link or something where I can understand what these tags mean - right now its pretty much guess work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [ICal4j](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page#Download) library to read/write ics file. The page also has usage examples.

The UID is basically an unique identifier. An example use case for UID is as follows:

Suppose A sent out an invite to B. Later on wants A wants to modify the same invite. When the modified invite reaches B the iCal application knows which local iCal to change based on the UID. The RFC for [iCalender](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) defines UID in section 4.8.4.7.

Wikipedia has a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) which has some helpful examples which can help you to understand the various tags

Comment: already did that. Thats how I was able to get it work in Android. But my question was how to parse it further to get the exact information and what do tags like UID mean?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. Also found [this](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/) which is quite helpful. Didn't think a home project would get so complicated, good exercise though!